# How to manage ownership of contract while deploying

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I have three contracts: Contract1.sol, Contract2.sol, Contract2.sol.

And this truffle migration file:

```
const _startBlock = 18;
module.exports = async function (deployer) {
  deployer
    .deploy(Contract1)
    .then(async function (instance) {
      deployer.deploy(
        Contract2,
        instance.address,
        _startBlock
      );
    });

  deployer.deploy(Contract3);
};
```

My goal is to make:

```
Contract1 Owned by Contract2
Contract2 Owned by Contract3
```

How to manage this from truffle please ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to post them as they are and then transfer ownership.